# jquery closest tr and finding an element

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
<form name="frm1">
<table id="mytable" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            column1
        </td>
        <td>
            column2
        </td>
        <td>
            column3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ABC
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="mydd" class="mydd">
                <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
                <option value="DECF">DECF</option>
                <option value="GHHHH">GHHHH</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="textvalue" id="textvalue" value="kljaslkjd">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ABC
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="mydd" class="mydd">
                <option value="222">222</option>
                <option value="333">333</option>
                <option value="444">444</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="textvalue" name="textvalue" id="textvalue" value="kljaslkjd">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

jquery code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mydd").change(function(){
      var value= $(this).closest("tr").find(".textvalue").attr("name");
       alert('value:' + value);
    });
});
```

What I am trying to do is, when I change the drop down option, I am getting the closest tr, and then finding for an input element. The first element is always returning undefined. But the second element works fine. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you that you always always use both options for your html tags (name, id) because you can have two elements with the same name and there's no problem at all, but the id it has to be unique and the id is what it's important for javascript, and the name is important for the server language like PHP.

And the input tags from where you are triggering this, have no class textvalue, so maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The first `<input>` is missing the `textvalue` class. Change

```
<input type="text" name="textvalue" id="textvalue" value="kljaslkjd">
```

to

```
<input type="text" class="textvalue" name="textvalue" id="textvalue" value="kljaslkjd">
```

The markup also contains multiple elements with duplicate IDs, which is invalid HTML. So also change the first `id="textvalue"` to `id="textvalue1"` and the second to `id="textvalue2"`.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated IDs - they'll get you every time. That could be the issue here. Secondly, the first one doesn't have the right class - or a class, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` in the first row has no `class="..."`.
Therefore, `.textvalue` doesn't find it.